# C: Return even number in array program by using pointers, why does my program crush after printing the result

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This is my simple program that generate a array of N integers, print it, and it will call the getevennumber function, and the function will return the pointer addresses of the even numbers in array. and the main program will print the even numbers in the array:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int* getEvenNumber(int a[]);

    int main (){
        int N;
        printf("Enter N: ");
        scanf("%d", &N);
        int array[N], i;
        int *test[N];
        srand(time(NULL));
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {

            array[i] = (rand() % 100)+1;
            printf("%d \n", array[i]);

        }
        printf("------- \n");
        *test = getEvenNumber(array);
        for(i = 0; i <= sizeof(test); i++){
            printf("%d \n", *test[i] );
        }


        return 0;
    }

    int* getEvenNumber(int a[]){
        int i,j = 0;
        int* ptr[j];
        for(i = 0; i  <= sizeof(a); i++)
        {

         if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
               ptr[j] = &a[i];
               printf("%d\n",*ptr[j]);
               j++;
           }
        }
         return *ptr;

    }
```

currently the problem is: when I run the program, it will print the desired even numbers, then the program will also print 2 random data address then crushes, here is an example output:

N: 10
66
19
70
54
84
12
35
56
53
19

---

66
70
54
84
19
1981890690
-1090571325
(program crushed)

Can someone help me identify the problem please, thank you!

Comment: examine your code:          int i,j = 0;
        int* ptr[j];

Comment: You are also trying to fill an array inside a function so you need to pass a pointer to the array, int ** arrayPtr for example.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading your code, you're returning a pointer to a local variable, which means all hell breaks loose when you use it in the calling code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function `getEvenNumber`, you're creating a local variable `ptr` which adress you are returning. You should not do that, because local variables only exist within a function, and **never** outside of it. Also, you are actually returning the value of the first element of ptr (because you are dereferencing it). This is why `*test[i]` fails, because you never return the actual array and thus cannot iterate over it with `[i]`.

The best solution would be to declare the array in the main function and pass it like this `getEvenNumber(int a[], int *ptr[])`

And don't declare your array with size zero... (as you are currently doing with ptr).

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i = 0; i <= sizeof(test); i++){
        printf("%d \n", *test[i] );
    }
```

sizeof(test) isn't the number of elements in the array test, it's sizeof(int*) which is 8 (bytes), assuming you're on a 64-bit system. It's returning the size of a pointer to a memory address, not the actual length of the array. So your loop goes outside the bounds of the array which probably causes your problem.

Also you're returning a local variable, which can cause additional problems.